# WiX - Custom Action (after installation) does not run on upgrade

Tags: wix, upgrade, action

I have created a custom action that gets triggered via UI. It works fine for new install but fails during upgrade. However, if I run a repair from control panel, it then runs fine. I tried capturing msi log but it does not give any clue. Here are the snippets...

UI:

```
<Control Id="CloseButton" Type="PushButton" X="230" Y="243" Width="66" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="&amp;Continue">    
  <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="ConfigureServer1">1</Publish>   
  <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>    
</Control>
```

Custom Action:

```
<CustomAction Id="ConfigureServer1" Impersonate="no" Directory="TARGETDIR" Return="asyncNoWait" ExeCommand="[#fileSetupDb] &quot;[ProductVersion]&quot; &quot;[OCISUPGRADE]&quot;"></CustomAction>
```

Sequence for the UI file:

```
<InstallUISequence>
......
 <Show Dialog="FinishedForm" OnExit="success" />
......
</InstallUISequence>
```

Any clues.... or anything I can try to debug etc.? I tried for a couple of days with no results. I am not a newbie in msi or wix and not an expert either.

Comment: Fail how? which error code? Can't you post the upgrade log?

Comment: Fails means it just does not execute the custom action!

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely follow the question but I'll take a guess. When upgrading the "previous version of the product" (the MSI being removed) only has its InstallExecuteSequence run. So the custom action in the old version of the product in the InstallUISequence won't run.

If the question is why the custom action won't run in the new version of the product, then there isn't enough information here. You can look in the verbose log file to see what the result of the custom action with the matching Id.